# Why is rspec example with AJAX not working correctly?

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I am having a problem with running integration tests that contain ajax in them.

For example the test below

```
scenario 'displays next page when scrolling to the bottom of the page', js: true do
  scroll_to_bottom_of_page
  wait_for_ajax

  expect(all('.follow-up').count).to eq(30)
end
```

Implementation for scroll_to_bottom of page method

```
def scroll_to_bottom_of_page
  page.execute_script "$('.off-canvas-wrap').scrollTo('.exit-off-canvas');"
end
```

Implementation for wait_for_ajax method

```
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

I basically want to test that my infinite scrolling functionality is working.

When I change the script to the following it works fine.

```
scenario 'displays next page when scrolling to the bottom of the page', js: true do
  scroll_to_bottom_of_page
  sleep 1

  expect(all('.follow-up').count).to eq(30)
end
```

This isn't very reliable. What if the ajax call takes more than 1 second. I am not a huge fan of adding sleep 1 or 2 or 3 randomly around.

Please any help in finding out what is wrong with the wait_for_ajax would be appreciated.

Thanks.

I have just finished creating a test app. Please check it out

https://github.com/ryannealmes/capybara-bug

Comment: what web driver are you using with Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting on the capybara forums, I have found out that some selectors have wait for async calls to finish and some don't. All I had to do to get this spec to pass was to update the expectation to the below

```
expect(page).to have_css('.follow-up', count: 30)
```

Some useful resources I was passed on are listed below if you ever run into this and want to understand more.

- https://speakerdeck.com/timmoore/embracing-capybara
- http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/dm86-R5anrE